# Would you like to help promote the site by giving away pencils?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So I made up these DIY pencils:

[image: look our diy pencils are awesome]

They look great AND I have oodles of them. If you'd like to give these away, such as at a local hardware store or leaving them at a Habitat ReStore counter, that's cool. (Preferably, bring a small adorable child with you -- apparently, this makes the pencils move like hotcakes.) Just email me at **aarthi[at]stackexchange.com** with the following information:

- Your name
- Your home address
- How many pencils you want
- Where you're thinking about leaving/giving away the pencils.

That's it! I'm happy to send these out to wherever they need to go.

Comment: cool Idea!  I'd pass out a bunch to my buddies at the lumber yard, hardware store, box stores and coffee stop. These are something builders and DIYer's love. Simple, cheap and effective. Good Call Aarhti.

Comment: These pencils also work great for opening beer bottles. Y'know... *After* you're done measuring, cutting, etc.

Comment: @Shog9 opening a beer with a pencil? Pics/links or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Kate: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/files/368/01530abddbe94826a381ec2c003a913d/pasted-image-png

Comment: @Shog9 Spectacular. Are you an engineer? If not, I might declare you an honourary one

Comment: No engineering background whatsoever, @Kate - but I'll certainly drink to honor, deserved or otherwise ;-)